# Why isn't golang duck typing not working for me in my code below?

Tags: go

In the code below, I'm trying to create concrete implementations of a Model interface and API interface:

```
package main

import "fmt"

/////////

type Model interface {
    ID() string
}

type API interface {
    Create(Model)
}

/////////

type ConcreteModel struct {}

func (model ConcreteModel) ID() string {
    return "123"
}

func (model ConcreteModel) Name() string {
    return "aron"
}

type ConcreteAPI struct{}

func (api ConcreteAPI) Create(model ConcreteModel) {
    fmt.Println("Created concrete model with id " + model.ID() + ", name " + model.Name())
}

func main() {
    // invocation via interface
    func(api API) {
        api.Create(ConcreteModel{})
    }(ConcreteAPI{})
}
```

Utterly confusing to me is why I get the following error when running this code:

```
ConcreteAPI does not implement API (wrong type for Create method)
        have Create(ConcreteModel)
        want Create(Model)
```

From what I glean about golang ducktyping, it would seem that ConcreteAPI should be fulfilling the contract of Create(Model) because `ConcreteModel` has the required methods of `Model`, namely `ID() string`.

The reason I want to try to do something like this is that `func(api API)` is a stand-in for something that knows how to play with concrete API implementations, in my intended real-world codebase.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to make whats above actually work?

Comment: function's arg type should be equal

Comment: There is no duck typing in go, and `ConcreteAPI` doesn't implement the `API` interface because `API` has a method `Create(Model)`  and `ConcreteAPI` doesn't.

Comment: "Does anybody have suggestions on how to make whats above actually work?" Yes: Stop thinking in traditional OOP and redesign.

Answer (score 0):

ConcreteAPI doesn't implements API's method ,please you can add:

func( concreteApi *ConcreteAPI )  Create(Model){}

but you have another error see detail below:
ConcreteModel also doesn't implements  Model

Comment: Thanks Yu Peng, I was trying to avoid that approach as it requires casting:

`func (api ConcreteAPI) Create(model Model) {
    fmt.Println("Created concrete model with id " +  model.(ConcreteModel).ID() + ", name " +  model.(ConcreteModel).Name())
}`

but that does seem like the only way to do what I want unfortunately, as I would like ConcreteAPI to work explicitly with ConcreteModel in its signature (so I can't throw a different implementation of Model into its Create method)